# How to shredding array with regx pattern in unified text?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-replace

I'm converting text from a txt file into an array.I need to shred the texts in this array using regex.

This is the array in my text file.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 65S34523APPLE IS VERY BEAUTIFUL6.000TX786.34563.675 234.89
    [1] => 06W01232BOOK IS SUCCESSFUL1.000YJ160.00021.853 496.00
    [2] => 67E45643DO YOU HAVE A PEN? 7/56.450EQ9000.3451.432 765.12
)
```

if I need to explain a line as an example,

input => 65S34523APPLE IS VERY BEAUTIFUL6.000TX786.34563.675 234.89

required sections => **65S34523** **APPLE IS VERY BEAUTIFUL** 6.000 **TX** **786.345** 63.67 5 234.89

target I want :

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 65S34523
        [1] => APPLE IS VERY BEAUTIFUL
        [2] => TX
        [3] => 786.345
    )
```

I need multiple regex patterns to achieve this.I need to shred the data I want in order in a loop.but since there is no specific layout, I don't know what to choose according to the regex patterns.

I've tried various codes to smash this array.

```
$smash = 
array('65S34523APPLE IS VERY BEAUTIFUL6.000TX786.34563.675 234.89', 
      '06W01232BOOK IS SUCCESSFUL1.000YJ160.00021.853 496.00',
      '67E45643DO YOU HAVE A PEN? 7/56.450EQ9000.3451.432 765.12');
```

I'm trying to foreach and parse the array.For example, I tried to get the text first.

```
foreach ($smash as $row) {
    $delete_numbers = preg_replace('/\d/', '', $smash);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($delete_numbers);
echo "</pre>";
```

While it turned out it was that way.

```
Array
(
    [0] => SAPPLE IS VERY BEAUTIFUL.TX.. .
    [1] => WBOOK IS SUCCESSFUL.YJ.. .
    [2] => EDO YOU HAVE A PEN? /.EQ.. .
)
```

Naturally, this is not what I want.Each array has a different structure.So i have to check with if-else too.

> As you can see in the example, there is no pure text.Here
>   **TX**,**YJ**,**EQ** should be deleted.The **dots** should be wiped using apples.The **first letters** at the beginning of the text should
>   be removed.The remaining **special characters** must be removed.

I have tried many of the above.I have looked at alternative examples.

**AS A RESULT**;

I'm in a dead end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kkog5))

```
$smash = ['65S34523APPLE IS VERY BEAUTIFUL6.000TX786.34563.675 234.89', 
          '06W01232BOOK IS SUCCESSFUL1.000YJ160.00021.853 496.00',
          '67E45643DO YOU HAVE A PEN? 7/56.450EQ9000.3451.432 765.12'];

foreach ($smash as $line) {
    $result[] = preg_match('~(\w+\d)(\D+)[^A-Z]+([A-Z]{2})(\d+\.\d{3})~', $line, $out) ? array_slice($out, 1) : [];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '65S34523',
    1 => 'APPLE IS VERY BEAUTIFUL',
    2 => 'TX',
    3 => '786.345',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '06W01232',
    1 => 'BOOK IS SUCCESSFUL',
    2 => 'YJ',
    3 => '160.000',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '67E45643',
    1 => 'DO YOU HAVE A PEN? ',
    2 => 'EQ',
    3 => '9000.345',
  ),
)
```

My pattern assumes:

1. The first group will consist of numbers and letters and conclude with a digit.
2. The second group contains no digits.
3. The third group is consistently 2 uppercase letters.
4. The fourth group will reliably have three decimal places.

---

p.s. If you don't want that pesky trailing space after `PEN?`, you could use this:

https://3v4l.org/9XpA6

```
~(\w+\d)([^\d ]+(?: [^\d ]+)*) ?[^A-Z]+([A-Z]{2})(\d+\.\d{3})~
```

Comment: Notice there is the trailing space after `PEN?`.  I don't know if you need that to be removed or not.

Comment: Actually there should be no spaces.

Comment: Would have been clearer for me if you gave exact desired result for all 3 elements.  I'll review my pattern.

Comment: I chose 3 as an example because the indexes are different.No problem.Does this pattern fail when data is not available?For example if the "TX" is not in the array.

Comment: I'd rather not get sucked into a perpetual question.  However, if you would like to provide 3 more of your trickier fringe case strings, I will have a look and suggest a pattern adjustment.  Please comment me a link (like my 3v4l demo link) which has 3 new strings and tell me the the desired output as a comment block in the demo's code area.

Comment: I think I added an example of all the variables in the list.https://3v4l.org/hUHD4